# High values of the communication range between two vehicles

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I use OMNeT++-4.6, sumo-0.22.0 and Veins-4a2.

I measured the distance between two bikes (in my scenario vehicles are considered as bikes and I modified my rou.xml file by adding vClass="bicycle") during a contact in my simulation and I had very high distance values: up to 1800m.

Normally, using the 802.11p model, the communication range is 15-20 meters in Europe.

I did not understand well these high values, can someone explain me please if it is a normal case else where does the problem come from ?

Comment: Which attenuation models and decider configuration do you use? The communication range is highly dependent on those values. Also the configuration of the ConnectionManager is important to know for helping you.

Comment: I used TwoRayInterferenceModel and SimpleObstacleShadowing as attenuation models and Decider80211p as decider configuration. For the ConnectionManager, I changed only nic.phy80211p.maxTXPower to 20mW.

Comment: Why do you think there is a comminication distance from only 30m?

Comment: It is indicated in the research article "Performance Comparison of IEEE 802.11p and IEEE 802.11b for Vehicle-to-Vehicle Communications in Highway, Rural, and Urban Areas" that the standards of the dedicated short range communication (DSRC) has different features, the communication range in Europe is 15-20 meters. In my scenario I obtained values up to 1800 meters, I did not understand the reason.

Comment: In Europe, IEEE 802.11p is used, too. It also uses the 5.9 GHz band and therefore, is also able to reach high distances. I don't know, why the article states that the communication range in Europe is only 15-20m.

Comment: So according to you, is it normal to obtain distance values up to 1800m in my simulation using veins (knowing that vehicles are considered as bicycles in my scenario and the maximum speed value is defined to 20 km/h) ?

Comment: I found also another information in this link "https://books.google.fr/books?id=glt4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=802.11p+europe+distance&source=bl&ots=sm0BCwOQvz&sig=2FQiA2fToAEqeakPpWvDCZy_MU0&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3kd_S1rvXAhVHPBoKHQ77DVsQ6AEIaDAF#v=onepage&q=802.11p%20europe%20distance&f=false" that the IEEE 802.11p range can reach up to 300 m.

Answer (score 2):

ETSI ITS G5 is using IEEE 802.11p as transmission technology.

Someone can find many publications stating about different transmission distances while using IEEE 802.11p as transmission technology.

The article `Evaluating the Impact of Transmission Range on the Performance of VANET` mentions a communication distance up to one kilometer.

But, the transmission distance highly depends on the simulated scenario as various obstacles (cars, buildings, ...) may influence the maximum transmission distance significantly.

Also, the simulation accuracy of the physical transmission and the radio medium will influence the calculated transmission range.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used the parameters of Veins simulator, this is why I wanted to check if it is a normal value or not.

Comment: As I said.. this highly depends on your used scenario. If there is line of sight between the bicycles and so on.. So i guess there is no way of to say that your values are correct or not?